# Linux zip selected folder and create a download link for zipped file

Tags: linux, server, ftp, zip

My current directory contains `web`,`api`,`logs`,and `some-backup-directory`. I want to zip only `web` and `api` directory in a single zipped archive and create a direct download link for it, so i will download it over `http://` from anywhere because downloading over `ftp` connection will take more time and also don't allow me to do other tasks on server at the same time. I am using this command to zip the files on server

```
zip -r mybackup-web.zip /home/projects/web
zip -r mybackup-api.zip /home/projects/api
```

But it will create two zip files, i need both in one.
I am using `windows 7` in my local and `Debian 8` on server. I am using `putty` to connect to the server and execute server commands.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Your question is also pretty unclear. For example *"transfer my files from my local to server using ftp connection"* is ambiguous. It's not clear if your download or upload files from the *"server"*. What is *"download link"*? Do you mean HTTP? If you do, your question is not even answerable. We do not know if your even run web server on the *"server"*. And even if you do, how is that web server configured to map local paths to URLs.

Comment: And your question is also too broad. Zipping and link generation are two completely separate questions.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl ok i will move it to super user and will add more details in it. thanks for help

Comment: @MartinPrikryl i got the solution, thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using zip**

What you are doing actually works according to `zip`'s man page:

```
zip -r <target> <dir1> # Add files from dir1 to archive
zip -r <target> <dir2> # Add files from dir2 to archive
```

If you execute both commands **from the same working directory**, the second command updates the existing zip file rather than create a new one.

**Using tar**

You could also use `tar`:

`tar -zcvf <target>.tar <dir1> <dir2> ...`

Flags:

- c: Create a new archive containing the specified items
- v: Produce verbose output (OPTIONAL)
- f: Write the archive to the specified file
- z: Compress using gzip

In your case:

`tar -zcvf mybackup.zip /home/projects/web /home/projects/api`

You can later **extract** it using:

`tar -zxvf mybackup.zip`

Comment: but it will create a `.tar` file i need `.zip` and also how to create a direct download link of this

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR, the zip solution should work as well. About the hosting, this is a very broad question. Please specify your platform and needs.

Comment: i added the platforms details in my question

Comment: i also change the backup file names, so no confusion made there for overwriting the files

Comment: yeah, i got that, i can make a `.tar` file and move it in `public` directory so i can download it over `http` as `http://example.com/backup.tar`